Can use figures from software documentation licensed under Apache2 in a conference paper?
I'm writing a paper that will be published in a conference. It is a technical paper, and I am discussing my use of a software framework licensed under Apache 2.0. Their documentation has an image I would like to include in my paper. Is this allowed?
